# pytorch runs in anaconda prompt but not in python idle

Tags: python, module, installation, pytorch, python-idle

I know this question might be stupid, but I couldn't find any help on the internet. Recently I installed anaconda in my computer, it runs Windows 10 x64. Then I used anaconda prompt to download and install pytorch for 3.6 python:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cuda100 -c pytorch
```

After the installation I verified in anaconda's prompt that pytorch is installed:

```
>>> Python
>>> Import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

I also checked conda list and indeed pytorch is installed in my machine.
However, I write Python code in python 3.6.7 IDLE, not in anaconda prompt, so, whenever I try to import pytorch I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pytorch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch'
```

For some reason, Anacoda prompt recognizes pytorch, but not IDLE. Is there any solution for this? Is there any way to import pytorch module to IDLE?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install idle ? This is due to python path issues.

Comment: I used python website

Comment: The is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693893/no-module-named-torch-on-python-idle, which is a duplicate of several similar questions.  To repeat my comment: Exceptions appearing in IDLE's Shell are generated by the python binary that is running IDLE. ModuleNotFoundError means that the module was not found by python in any directory on that executing binary's sys.path. Run 'import sys; print(sys.executable, sys.path)' to see both the python executable and its path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the python used by idle is not the one from anaconda. In python it's very common to have multiple [environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), and you always need to be aware of which environment is activated. To see what environment is activated, you can do something in this in anaconda and idle

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
```

If they have different paths, you need to first figure out how to stay in a specific environment in idle.

Answer (score 0):

did you type "import torch" in Anaconda prompt but "import **py**torch" in idle?
if yes, that is simply the issue, so type "import torch" in any idle not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).